# How To Create Custom Site Map Provider in MOSS

Tags: 2007

I need to create a custom sitemap provider for a sharepoint 2007 site.Can anyone send me links which can help me to create custom sitemap providers, I need some simple examples.

ThankYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog contains a tutorial.

[How To Create Custom XML SiteMapProvider and Render it in SharePoint 2007](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/syedi/how-to-create-custom-xmlsitemapprovider-and-render-it-in-sharepoint-2007-moss)

I would recommend using SPWebConfigModification to modify the Web.config