# Creating Custom Site Navigation for SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, development, navigation, site-collection

I want to create Custom Site Navigation "Breadcrumb navigation" which will show where a user came from, ATM I am using default Navigation that shows where this specific web is located in the site collection, not where I came from.

Its a big Issue since we linked up different sites by providing links. I did my research and I know I can create a Custom User control & add few line of code in web.config to create a custom sitemap navigation, but I am not sure how does this entire process works. So A complete guide would be the prefect answer :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already discussed here on a similar thread :- [How To Create Custom Site Map Provider in MOSS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/how-to-create-custom-site-map-provider-in-moss)

If you are looking for step by step kind of guide , you can certainly refer to these links below:

http://blogs.livepoint.com.au/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=2ff3c115-1800-4d20-992d-b48842982db3&ID=22

http://meandmysharepoint.blogspot.in/2011/11/customising-sharepoint-global.html

This should get you started with custom sitemap provider comfortably on SP 2007.

Concerning breadcrumbs hope these links will help you get started. It all requires writing some amount of c# code as well.

http://techguru.enurac.com/post/MOSS-2007-WCM-Development-Part-1-e28093-Custom-Breadcrumb-control.aspx
http://deewaker-blogs.blogspot.in/2009/05/custom-bradcrumb-in-sharepoint-2007.html
http://aspnetcoe.wordpress.com/2006/09/28/moss-2007-wcm-development-part-1/
[Custom breadcrumb?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24180/custom-breadcrumb)

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but I got different requirements in comparison to that question, and I already seen the link you have posted, but my case is "I want to create Custom Site Navigation "Breadcrumb navigation" which will show where a user came from,"

Comment: I have updated my answer with a few links that can help you with breadcrumbs for moss 2007